# Javascript optimizing if statement

Tags: javascript

Is there a way of compressing this `if` statement?

```
var alive1 = true   
if (x2 >= (x10 - 10) && x2 <= (x10 + 10) && y2 >= (y10 - 10) && y2 <= (y10 + 10) || x3 >= (x10 - 10) && x3 <= (x10 + 10) && y3 >= (y10 - 10) && y3 <= (y10 + 10) || x4 >= (x10 - 10) && x4 <= (x10 + 10) && y4 >= (y10 - 10) && y4 <= (y10 + 10) || x5 >= (x10 - 10) && x5 <= (x10 + 10) && y5 >= (y10 - 10) && y5 <= (y10 + 10)|| x6 >= (x10 - 10) && x6 <= (x10 + 10) && y6 >= (y10 - 10) && y6 <= (y10 + 10)) {
    alive1 = false;
}
```

Comment: this many condition then you are doing somthing wrong , otherwise go for array .

Comment: In any case, you can use [closure compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home).

Comment: Just an observation, I know what you mean by "compressing" but that is going to be confusing to others in this context. I think you want to say "cleaning up" or "optimizing".

Comment: Just make an array of the values you're comparing to x10 and y10, and map over that shiz

Comment: what format does the variables have? what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can't really "compress" the code, but you can make it more readable.

You are checking pairs of numbers against the same condition, so an array of pairs is probably the best way forward.

You could also speed up the performance and readability a bit more by calculating `x10 - 10` etc outside the `for` loop.

```
var alive1 = true;

var minX = x10 - 10;
var maxX = x10 + 10;
var minY = y10 - 10;
var maxY = y10 - 10;

var coords = [[x2,y2], [x3,y3], [x4,y4], [x5,y5], [x6,y6]];

// loop each [x,y] pair
for(var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
    var x = coords[i][0];
    var y = coords[i][1];
    if(x >= minX && x <= maxX && y >= minY && y <= maxY) {
        alive1 = false;
        // found a false condition, no need to continue the loop
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're simply checking if `x2` is within 10 of `x10` and `y2` is within 10 of `y10`, and so on, you can change it to:

```
if (Math.abs(x2 - x10) <= 10 && Math.abs(y2 - y10) <= 10 && ...) {
    alive1 = false;
}
```